# Nested objects queries into single array in Prisma

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, orm, prisma

In the Prisma Docs I found [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#select-specific-relation-fields) query:

[image]

and I would like to get instead of `posts: [ { title: 'My first post' }, { title: 'How to make cookies' } ]`, I get `posts: ['my first post', 'how to make cookies']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not directly possible in Prisma. You need to fetch the data and then map it as you require in your application itself.